# Change SQLAlchemy __tablename__

Tags: python-3.x, class, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using SQLAlchemy to handle requests from an API endpoint; my database tables (I have hundreds) are differentiated via a unique string (e.g. test_table_123)...

In the code below, `__tablename__` is static. If possible, I would like that to change based on the specific table I would like to retrieve, as it would be tedious to write several hundred unique classes.

```
from config import db, ma  # SQLAlchemy is init'd and tied to Flask in this config module

class specific_table(db.Model):
        __tablename__ = 'test_table_123'
        var1 = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
        var2 = db.Column(db.String, index=True)
        var3 = db.Column(db.String)

class whole_table_schema(ma.ModelSchema):
        class Meta:
                model = specific_table
                sqla_session = db.session

def single_table(table_name):

        # collect the data from the unique table
        my_data = specific_table().query.order_by(specific_table.level_0).all()
```

Thank you very much for your time in advance.

Comment: @needtobe - thank you for those suggestions/link. I'll get back to you on them after trying your suggestions.

Comment: @needtobe - thank you for your comments. I ended up solving it passing the table name received from the endpoint into functions

Comment: could you share the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `reflect` feature of SQLAlchemy.

`engine = db.engine`

`metadata = MetaData()`

`metadata.reflect(bind=engine)`

and finally
`db.session.query(metadata.tables[table_name])`

If you want smoother experience with querying, as previous solution cannot offer one, you might declare and map your tables: `tables = {table_name: create_table(table_name) for table_name in table_names}`, where `create_table` constructs models with different `__tablename__`. Instead of creating all tables at once, you can create them on demand.